# Get imports required for re-creating an object

Tags: python, python-import, code-analysis

Given an object produced during importing the code, produce the set of imports that are needed to execute that object creation code.

Case 1:

```py
some_obj = module.submodule.Class(42)
get_imports for_object(some_obj)
>>> "import module.submodule"
```

Case 2 (Sometimes the root module does not import submodules automatically (e.g. Airflow operators)):

```py
some_obj = submodule.Class(42)
get_imports for_object(some_obj)
>>> "from module import submodule"
```

Case 3 (stretch goal):

```py
some_obj = submodule.Class(sub2.Class2(42))
get_imports for_object(some_obj)
>>> ["from module import submodule", "from module2 import sub2"]
```

The goal is to produce import lines such that prepending them to object instantiation code will make the instantiation work.

Comment: "The goal is to produce import lines such that prepending them to object instantiation code will make the instantiation work.". Do you actually need to generate code, or are you just trying to create some kind of file that "represents" the object in a way that lets you re-create it later? Because, in the general case, that's what e.g. `pickle` is for. Just be aware that this kind of thing may carry security risks no matter how you go about it.

Comment: I want to generate code. Currently I use `inspect.getsource(some_func)`, but that's not enough due to type annotations in the signature using imported modules.

Answer (score 0):

This'll do:

```py
def get_object_imports(obj, sub_obj_class_name=None):
    sub_obj_modules = []
    if sub_obj_class_name is not None:
        for _, attribute_value in obj.__dict__.items():
            value_str = str(getattr(attribute_value,'__class__',''))
            if ('.' + sub_obj_class_name) in value_str:
                sub_obj_modules.append(attribute_value.__module__)

    if sub_obj_modules != []:
        sub_module_imports = [('import ' + sub_obj_module) for sub_obj_module
                              in sub_obj_modules]
        return ['import ' + obj.__module__] + sub_module_imports
    else:
        return 'import ' + obj.__module__
```

Cases (1) & (2) are equivalent, in that running either imports the same module. Note that with above, objects with same class names but *different module sources* will be included.

---

**Demo**:

```py
from module import class1
from other_module import submodule

obj1 = class1()
obj2 = obj1(submodule.class2())

print(get_object_imports(obj2, 'class2'))
# ['import module', 'import other_module.submodule']
```

Comment: >"Cases (1) & (2) are equivalent, in that running either imports the same module." 
It changes the variables in the namespace though. Also keep in mind that you can do `import airflow.operators.bash_operator; print(airflow.operators.bash_operator)`, but not `import airflow.operators; print(airflow.operators.bash_operator)`. I guess my question wasn't stated correctly as I actually want to make the source code line like `some_obj = submodule.Class(42)` work. I guess, deriving imports from object+source code of this object creation is too hard of a problem. I'm sorry for not thinking it through

Comment: @Ark-kun It actually doesn't change the output of `obj.__module__` - which is the only way I know of of accessing an obj's import module. Thus unless you can explicitly specify which to do `from x import y` vs `import x.y`, there's no way to do it 'intelligently'. Also, I'm rather unsure what it is you're looking for here - unless this `some_obj = submodule.Class(42)` is in a _different_  (non-`__main__`) module - then it's simple